# How can I send an image from Node.js to React.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, graphicsmagick

I have the following setup, by which I send the image, from its url, to be edited and sent back to be uploaded to S3. The problem I currently have is that the image gets on S3 corrupted, and I am wondering if there's trouble in my code that's causing the issue.

**Server side:**

```
function convertImage(inputStream) {
    return gm(inputStream)
        .contrast(-2)
        .stream();
}

app.get('/resize/:imgDetails', (req, res, next) => {
  let params = req.params.imgDetails.split('&');
  let fileName = params[0]; console.log(fileName);
  let tileType = params[1]; console.log(tileType);
  res.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
  let url = `https://${process.env.Bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/images/${tileType}/${fileName}`;
  convertImage(request.get(url)).pipe(res);
})
```

**Client side:**

```
axios.get('/resize/' + fileName + '&' + tileType)
    .then(res => {
     /** PUT FILE ON AWS **/
      var img = res;

      axios.post("/sign_s3_sized", {
        fileName : fileName,
        tileType : tileType,
        ContentType : 'image/jpeg'
      })
      .then(response => {
        var returnData = response.data.data.returnData;
        var signedRequest = returnData.signedRequest;
        var url = returnData.url;
        this.setState({url: url})

        // Put the fileType in the headers for the upload
        var options = {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
          }
        };

        axios.put(signedRequest,img, options)
        .then(result => {
          this.setState({success: true});
        }).bind(this)
        .catch(error => {
          console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    })
})
.catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Before going any further, I can assure you now that uploading any images via this setup minus the `convertImage()` works, otherwise the image gets put on S3 corrupted.

Any pointers as to what the issue behind the image being corrupted is? 
Is my understanding of streams here lacking perhaps? If so, what should I change?

Thank you!

EDIT 1:

I tried not running the image through the graphicsmagick API at all (`request.get(url).pipe(res);`) and the image is still corrupted.

EDIT 2:

I gave up at the end and just uploaded the file from Node.js straight to S3; it turned out to be better practice anyway.

Comment: Did you check that request.get is able to pull the image from s3 without any permission error? Try writing the content on server directory.

Comment: @CuriousMind yes, I just did, it retrieves it fine so I think we can rule out it being a CORS issue.

Comment: CORS shouldn't cause issue in server side application, its a browser thing. I was looking it from the perspective of public/authenticated access.

Comment: @CuriousMind Do you mean if the file has GET access allowed on the bucket? If so, then yes it is. When the new image is uploaded, it's pretty much the same size as the original, just corrupted.

Comment: I should mention I tried it with other public images (non-AWS ones), and the image is still corrupted.

Comment: Ok, that narrows down your problem. It should be problem with graphicsmagick api being invoked. Can you remove the call to gm API and directly write the `request.get` output to response? This is just to ensure whether gm APIs are causing problem.

Comment: @CuriousMind Ok, I just ditched the graphicsmagick API and wrote it directly from `request.get`, but the image is still corrupted. So I think the problem is now narrowed down to the stream/pipe issues again, sadly

Comment: I commented earlier that it was fixed, but I was just looking at the wrong image, apologies. The issue still persists.

Comment: Are you able to write image without gm API?

Comment: @CuriousMind I am able to able to write it to the cloud, but the image gets there corrupted, yes. That is, with and without the gm API.

Comment: did you try opening the file in text editor and see what is getting written to the file? Is it binary data or it is actually logging and error message.

Comment: @CuriousMind I did not, but I ended up going with another solution (see EDIT 2), thanks for your patience and help!

Answer (score 0):

So if you are end goal is to upload the image in the S3 bucket using Node Js, there are simple ways by using [multer-s3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3) node module.